# Why does my system say, "Save failed, hard drive removed," when I try to save my game?

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

I try to save my *WWE 2k14* data and it says, "Save failed, hard drive removed." What do I do to save my data?

Comment: What platform are you plaything this on?

Comment: Platform?what is that?

Comment: Playstation 3, Xbox 360, PS4, etc.?

Comment: Xbox 360 why is something wrong with it?

Comment: Please help me quick i still have my xbox on hoping for someone to help so i can save it

Comment: You could save it to the Cloud.

Comment: But since i havent saved it it says if you leave all your unsaved progress will be gone

Comment: Please help me someone

Comment: Is there not a hard drive in your 360?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your Hard Drive might be failing, which is an unfortunate thing to happen. However, is WWE 2K14 the only game doing this or are you getting this for other games as well? If this is the only game that does this,  then you could just format a flash drive and use it as a dedicated storage device for your Xbox.

Comment: Its for all the games

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the hard drive crashed. I'm having a problem where on my halo 4 server all of a sudden the multiplayer wouldn't work. The next day I got on  both my friend and brothers account was deleted. So you never know and I have xbox 360 slim, not that old red ring of death one.

Answer (score -1):

You might have a bad connecton berween the hardrive and hardrive connecter it happened to me

Comment: So...how would he fix it?

Comment: I had two buy a new one put your data on a pc the put it on your knew hardrive